# word2vec_basic.py - ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, word2vec

I got an error with running word2vec_basic.py on my mac both in PyCharm and Terminal('$ python word2vec_basic.py').

My mac version is as follows:
* platform: Darwin-15.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
* python: 3.6.0
* numpy: 1.12.1
* scipy: 0.19.0
* sklearn: 0.18.1

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/HYJ/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-35-c6c4cd8ccf88>", line 8, in <module>
    low_dim_embs = tsne.fit_transform(final_embeddings[:plot_only, :])
  File "/Users/HYJ/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py", line 884, in fit_transform
    embedding = self._fit(X)
  File "/Users/HYJ/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py", line 789, in _fit
    skip_num_points=skip_num_points)
  File "/Users/HYJ/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py", line 847, in _tsne
    **opt_args)
  File "/Users/HYJ/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/manifold/t_sne.py", line 388, in _gradient_descent
    grad_norm = linalg.norm(grad)
  File "/Users/HYJ/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/misc.py", line 129, in norm
    a = np.asarray_chkfinite(a)
  File "/Users/HYJ/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1215, in asarray_chkfinite
    "array must not contain infs or NaNs")
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

Comment: The error says you are passing an array which contains `inf`s or `NaN`s. Filter your array to remove them. If you need more help, you would need to post a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The script and the data are provided by TensorFlow. Some of other users also report the same problem and the recommended solutions are not working for my machine.

Comment: TensorFlow is constantly changing, scripts with inputs might have been with working with older version but not later versions. Without the script and the data it is close to impossible to help you.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/code/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py
This is the link! The script has a line for downloading the data from the web.

Comment: This looks like training of the word2vec model has diverged and NaNs appeared. Try using a lower learning rate.

Comment: Thank you but the original learning rate was 1.0 and I tried lower values to 0.1 and it still outputs the same error..